# Time complexity of merging of two hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

Does anyone know what the time complexity is of merging two hashes using ([Merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge)) function in ruby?

In my opinion, it would be O(n^2), since for each element in hash h1, all the elements in h2 should be checked and if two elements in two hashes have the same value, the key value of one of them should be changed.

I'm not sure if my assumption is correct or not. Can anyone help me find out what the time complexity is of merging hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong because there is no need to check whether `h1` and `h2` have any duplicate keys. The [merge method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) states that duplicate keys will default to the values in `h2`.

As for the real answer...you need to dig a little.

Checking the source on the `merge` method yields the following code

```
static VALUE
rb_hash_merge(VALUE hash1, VALUE hash2)
{
    return rb_hash_update(rb_obj_dup(hash1), hash2);
}
```

So keep going. The [Ruby source for `rb_hash_update`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/hash.c#1999) is this

```
rb_hash_update(VALUE hash1, VALUE hash2)
{
    rb_hash_modify(hash1);
    hash2 = to_hash(hash2);
    if (rb_block_given_p()) {
        rb_hash_foreach(hash2, rb_hash_update_block_i, hash1);
    }
    else {
        rb_hash_foreach(hash2, rb_hash_update_i, hash1);
    }
    return hash1;
}
```

And finally [the `rb_hash_foreach` source](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/hash.c#226)

```
rb_hash_foreach(VALUE hash, int (*func)(ANYARGS), VALUE farg)
{
    struct hash_foreach_arg arg;

    if (!RHASH(hash)->ntbl)
        return;
    RHASH_ITER_LEV(hash)++;
    arg.hash = hash;
    arg.func = (rb_foreach_func *)func;
    arg.arg  = farg;
    rb_ensure(hash_foreach_call, (VALUE)&arg, hash_foreach_ensure, hash);
}
```

One iteration across the hashes yields O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Your rational to get O(n^2) doesn't make sense. At most this is going to be an O(n+m) operation, where `n == h1.keys.length` and `m == h2.keys.length`

Here's how I'd write a merge operation:

- O(n): Create a new hash with the contents of h1: `h_new = h1.dup`

  - Assumes we need to loop over h1 to dup (likely a non-optimal solution)
- O(m): Iterate over the keys in `h2`: `h2.keys.each { }`

  - Foreach key in the loop, insert into `h_new[key] = h2[key]`

So the above algorithm produces an O(n+m) result.

Comment: Just to confirm, that is how Ruby does the merge (by default). Shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an element to a `Hash` has an asymptotic worst-case step complexity of O(n), but an asymptotic amortized worst-case step complexity of O(1). Merging is the same as adding all elements of the second `Hash` to the first `Hash`, so it has an asymptotic worst-case step complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>), but an asymptotic amortized worst-case step complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

> for each element in hash h1, all the elements in h2 should be checked
>   and if two elements in two hashes have the same value, the key value
>   of one of them should be changed.

There's a less complex way to achieve that:

```
h1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}

h2 = {
  a: 'hello',
  d: 4,
}

results = {}

h1.each do |key, val| 
  results[key] = val
end

h2.each do |key, val| 
  results[key] = val
end

p results
p h1.merge h2

--output:--
{:a=>"hello", :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
{:a=>"hello", :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
```

So `O(n)`.